# Error While make a relationship in mysql with 2 (varchar columns)

Tags: php, mysql

**First**  table `users`

```
 id         name
---------------------
  1         John
```

**Second** table `orders`

```
 id         order        name
----------------------------------
  1         pencil         John
```

The **sql** code to make a relationship with first column `name` in table `users`
And second column `name` in table `orders`

```
ALTER TABLE orders
ADD CONSTRAINT user_name
FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES users(name)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

it give me error

> errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

**How to Fix this proplem ??**

Comment: can you provide the SQL commands to create the tables?

the foreign key should be id, not name.  Name is not a key.  
so the Orders should be (id, order, user_id) and then you can have the constrained mapped out properly.

Comment: how can i make it name to name not id ??

Comment: Wow, on delete cascade, you like to leave dangerously :) To answer, did you checked the type of your two columns ? If they have different types (like one being `VARCHAR(N)` and the other `TINITEXT` it might throw an error.

Comment: :D they have the same type varchar 255 : )

Comment: CREATE TABLE Users (
    id int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

Answer (score 0):

So after searching I found that the solution is very simple :D
use the same **sql code**

```
ALTER TABLE orders
ADD CONSTRAINT user_name
FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES users(name)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

and make `name` *unique*  in the *parent column* .